# How to get first property of style attribute from HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div style="border: 2px solid; background-color: white; margin: 0px;">something</div>
```

Now I want to grab just `border: 2px solid`. I can do that using [regex](https://regex101.com/r/cQ4zQ8/1), But I'm sure all professional programmers recommend me to use a HTML parser for doing that.

---

In other word, how can I limit this code to just first property?

```js
$("body").html($("div").attr("style"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 2px solid; background-color: white; margin: 0px;">something</div>
```

Comment: just use $("div").css("border")

Comment: @DinoMyte Oh .. seems simple, tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use split, if you really want to get the whole `border: 2px solid`. 
If you need the `2px solid` only, then you can use `css()` function.

```js
$("body").html($("div").attr("style").split(';')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 2px solid; background-color: white; margin: 0px;">something</div>
```

```js
$("body").html($("div").css("border"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 2px solid; background-color: white; margin: 0px;">something</div>
```